# How to hide default menus in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I am new in Eclipse RCP plug in development.

I had written one plug-in with my own perspective and added perspective specific menus within it.

My question is how to hide the default menus provided within Eclipse, like Edit, Navigated, Search, Project ?

I tried with using '< extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions" >'
and putting my view specific condition, withing menu contribution's.

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards,

Mandar Phatak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [activities](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/). Example from my current project:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
  <activity
        id="arm.activity.disabled"
        name="%arm.activity.disabled.name">
     <enabledWhen>
        <with
              variable="selection">
           <count
                 value="-1">
           </count>
        </with>
     </enabledWhen>
  </activity>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="arm.activity.disabled"
        pattern="org\.eclipse\.m2e\..*">
  </activityPatternBinding>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="arm.activity.disabled"
        pattern="org\.eclipse\.search\..*">
  </activityPatternBinding>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="arm.activity.disabled"
        pattern="org\.eclipse\.team\..*">
  </activityPatternBinding>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="arm.activity.disabled"
        pattern="org\.eclipse\.compare.*">
  </activityPatternBinding>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="arm.activity.disabled"
        pattern="org\.eclipse\.help\.ui\.PrefPageHelp.*">
  </activityPatternBinding>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="arm.activity.disabled"
        isEqualityPattern="true"
        pattern="org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.Workspace">
  </activityPatternBinding>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="arm.activity.disabled"
        isEqualityPattern="true"
        pattern="org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.Perspectives">
  </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

Comment: Hello @Alexey, It partially works for me, but still not able to hide all menus. For e.g I am not able to hide the search->Remote, but can able to hide all others. Also for some menus, plug-in spy didn't show the 'active action definition identifier' instead show some Class name. Can we find the command names in that case ?

Comment: Yes, finding the correct IDs is sometimes a problem. You can set tracing options when starting your application (see http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/07/08/tip-tracing-keybindings-in-rcp/), but I don't remember if there is an option to trace menus opening.

Comment: what is the pattern for "Rename" context menu in project explorer? when we right click on a project and menu appears I want to disable the rename menu from that list

Comment: @wearybands I don't know, you may want to ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is in your rcp application you have a class that extends ActionBarAdvisor and in the constructor of the class you can do something like this for example to remove the edit menu

```
configurer.getMenuManager().remove(IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_EDIT);
```

All common eclipse menus like edit will have a constant defined in the class above, do that for the menu's you want to remove from your application.

This is only one approach I'm sure there might be others but hope this gets what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. But for menus I had used plug-in.xml. So is there any other way round by which I can hide the menus ( Preferably using plug-in.xml). I tried with the code above, but my Application class is implementing IApplication, so don't know how my ActionBarAdvisor will gets invoke.

Comment: One suggestion, would be to create a new plugin project select the option that it will make UI contributions then select create rcp application then select one of the templates and you will see the basic structure of an RCP app. I could be wrong but if you have an IApplication you must have a class that extends ActionBarAdvisor. Creating rcp example apps are a good starting point then try to use the code I put above and see if you can get the edit menu to not be displayed.