# Remove default menu in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, toolbar, menubar

I develop an Eclipse RCP application and I don't want to use the default menu and toolbar of my Eclipse. 
Here is my plugin.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

 <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="pmetest.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="PME Perspective"
            class="pmetest.ui.perspective.Perspective"
            id="pmetest.perspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            name="My FX View From PME"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            class="pmetest.ui.view.fx.MyViewPart"
            id="com.ongoladev.pmetest.MyViewPart">
      </view>
      <view
            class="pmetest.ui.view.FormView"
            id="com.ongoladev.pmetest.formview"
            name="FormView from PME"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="pmetest.application"
            name="Hello RCP">
         <property
               name="windowImages"
               value="icons/alt_window_16.gif,icons/alt_window_32.gif">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="pmetest.ui.command.CommandExit"
            id="com.ongoladev.pmetest.Exit"
            name="Exit">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="filemenuid"
               label="File My">
            <command
                  commandId="com.ongoladev.pmetest.Exit"
                  label="Exit application"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="Exit Application">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

and that is what I get
[image]

I want to remove all unnecessery manu and toolbar.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I inherited a 12-year-old application and in trying to update it to the latest Eclipse, ran into this problem of default menu items showing up. After trying multiple solutions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13833679/800140), I was left with the Run menu.

This brought me to this page.  I used the solution by @ShahzadIftikhar above and tweaked it.

To be specific, we have a class that extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor and that class contained a postWindowOpen method that only called super.postWindowOpen().  After that call, I added the below code to specifically block the inclusion of the "Run" menu.  This menu contained the "Add V8/Chrome JavaScript Exception Breakpoint" and External Tools menu items that were definitely not needed and the client specifically said "get rid of them".

```
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IContributionItem[] items = ((WorkbenchWindow) workbenchWindow).getMenuBarManager().getItems();
    for (IContributionItem item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.run")) {
            item.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

Once you get this block of code in your application, you should be able to just use the item ID for whatever you want to block.

Answer (score 1):

For removing all defaults options in menu, You need to add this below code in ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java class.

```
@Override
public void postWindowOpen() { 
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IContributionItem[] items = ((WorkbenchWindow)workbenchWindow).getMenuBarManager().getItems();
    for (IContributionItem item : items) {
            item.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get full control over the menus and tool bar your application can use its own `ActionBarAdvisor` derived class. When you do this you create all the items yourself.

The action bar advisor is created in `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class which in turn is created from your `WorkbenchAdvisor` class.

If you create a RCP plugin project using the 'RCP application with a view' example Eclipse will create examples of these classes for you.